# Trigger bootstrap modal if a condition statement is not met

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, alert, bootstrap-modal

Instead of using the default jquery alert popup, I'd like to trigger a Bootstrap Modal. All the tutorials I've read, the modal is triggered by the `click(function(){});`. I'd like to have if triggered if a condition in my "if statement" is not met. Here is the code I have

```js
var test1 = $('#test').val();

$('#go').click(function() {
  if (test1 === "") {
    alert("Please enter all values in the fields");
    $('#myModal').modal('show');
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="test" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Test</label>
  <div class="col-sm-3">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="test" placeholder="Enter A Value">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="col-sm-offset-6 col-sm-3">
    <button type="button" id="go" class="btn btn-primary">Go</button>
  </div>
</div>
<!--Modal-->
<div class="modal fade" id="#myModal">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>

        </button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>

      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div>
<!-- /.modal -->
<!--End Modal-->
```

Comment: I just want to add that both @joshcrozier and user1833408 both gave proper answers. joshcrozier answered my question and  user1833408 pointed out that I need to tidy up my code, thanks to both of them

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your case, since the modal has an `id` of `id="#myModal"`, you need to escape the `#` within the jQuery selector, `$('#\\#myModal').modal('show')`:

```js
$('#go').click(function() {
  var test1 = $('#test').val();

  if (test1 === "") {
    $('#\\#myModal').modal('show');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="test" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Test</label>
  <div class="col-sm-3">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="test" placeholder="Enter A Value">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="col-sm-offset-6 col-sm-3">
    <button type="button" id="go" class="btn btn-primary">Go</button>
  </div>
</div>
<!--Modal-->
<div class="modal fade" id="#myModal">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>

        </button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>

      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Please enter all values in the fields.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div>
<!-- /.modal -->
<!--End Modal-->
```

Comment: that works great, thank you, but can you tell me why it  works even if you type something in the input box?

Comment: @mcadamsjustin It's because you were grabbing the value of the input element prior to the elements being loaded on the page. Thus, the value was always an empty string. See the update. You could have also wrapped the code with `$(document).on('ready', function () { ... });`

Comment: in the full code I do have it wrapped in  `$(document).ready` guess I should've mentioned that. So thanks for clearing that up

Answer (score 2):

Remove the '#' from the id and your code should work

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal">
```

Comment: thanks for the duh moment, I guess it's pretty much the same answer, just in a different way